# How to display shopping cart total in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, shopping-cart, cart, prestashop-1.6

could anyone help me how to modify some tpl files in Prestashop 1.6 to show not only the number of products in cart but also the order total like this (before having mouse over).

Cart: $1150 (3)

where:

$1150 - is the order total
(3) - number of products in cart

Thanks a lot!
Tereza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the total order price is already in the templates, but is hidden  by CSS:

[blockcart.css#L53-L54](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/themes/default-bootstrap/css/modules/blockcart/blockcart.css#L53-L54)

Comment out this rule to see the total price in cart block summary. Notice that I linked the file in default theme, your theme may be different.

To move the total price before the product count you'll have to edit the module template:

[blockcart.tpl#L35-L45](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/themes/default-bootstrap/modules/blockcart/blockcart.tpl#L35-L45)

Move the whole span element (note the content inside it and closing tag) to before line 32.

And these are the constant that you can use to replace `BOTH_WITHOUT_SHIPPING`:

[Cart.php#L147-L154](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Cart.php#L147-L154)

Please be aware that I linked files from `1.6.1.x` branch, which corresponds to the latest version of `1.6.1`: `1.6.1.4`. You should check in you own shop files for these constants.

I couldn't find any info for these constants, so you should probably try them out yourself. I'd begin with trying `BOTH` constant.

Upload these modified files to FTP.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am nearly there. The only thing missing is that I would like to display the total price with shipping. What value should I insert instead of "Cart::BOTH_WITHOUT_SHIPPING'" ?
Thank you one more time!

Comment: Thank you very much. "BOTH" works, the only issue is, that it is not updating the total price after you add something to the basket, you have to refresh the whole page to get the total amount without mouseover. You can try it at [vonaveauto.cz](http://vonaveauto.cz) But I am afraid there is no solution for that.

Comment: Hello, when I add a product the price refreshes for me. Maybe you have a javascript error in a specific browser?

Comment: It updates the price for the products, so it is for example 119 CZK + 119 CZK, but just after the refresh it is also with the shipping, so 119 + 119 + 50.

Comment: You need to edit this line: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/themes/default-bootstrap/js/modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js#L790 : change `jsonData.productTotal` to `jsonData.total`